# How to change file permissions as a member of group

Tags: python, macos

I wish to change the permissions of a file that I am not the owner of, but have group rwx access to.  When I try something like `chmod 777 <file>`, I get an the following error:

```
chmod: Unable to change file mode on <file>: Operation not permitted
```

Is there a way to change file permission as a group member WITHOUT using sudo?  Ultimately, I wish to script such a task in Python and do not want the hassle of dealing with passwords/root.

Answer (score 1):

> You can only change permissions for files and folders of which you are
>   the owner.

From:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2963